# HDRI light not working

Tags: hdri

I tried to make them with the help of tutorials but every time the object is black [image]

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share the file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The HDRI preview spheres at the right bottom are black, too. This indicates that the problem is not related to the model itself, but is a problem with the graphics card/driver or a bug. Maybe try the older 2.93 LTS version of Blender or update the GPU driver?

Comment: Are you using an image texture instead of an environmental texture?